# Android Studio - How do I make my RecyclerView contain more items after a button press?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've created a RecyclerView with editTexts which size is defined by an integer in the adapters constructor, however now I want to implement a Button that increases that integer by one and that way adds another editText to my recyclerView. The problem is that I don't know how to update the size of the recyclerView after it's first created, here is the code and what I've tried so far.

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private int playerAmount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playerAmount = 6;

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclyerViewNames);

    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, playerAmount);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}

public void addPlayers(View view){
    playerAmount++;
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("players",String.valueOf(playerAmount));
    Log.d("players in adapter",String.valueOf(recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
}
```

}

Adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
int playerAmount;

public MyAdapter(Context ct, int players){
    context = ct;
    playerAmount = players;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_name, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return playerAmount;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    EditText editText;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editname);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you just have to update the adapter's list and then have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` and everything else will be taken care by Android itself.

In your case you didn't created a list at all. You are missing few things in your adapter implementation.

I would recommend go through this documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

You will find the sample code link by Google at the end of the page and also try that to have better understanding of `Recylerview`, that way you will be in better position to proceed further.